# Radgrid GridTemplateColumn Not Displaying on all rows

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datagrid, telerik, radgrid

I have an `aspx` page, however I am experiencing a strange problem.

I have a RadGrid datagrid in my webpage, I'm binding the data on the client side using JavaScript. I have created a GridTemplateColumn in the RadGrid, see below code:

```
     <td colspan="2">
            <telerik:RadGrid ID="OrderLines" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="1" AllowMultiRowEdit="True" MasterTableView-EditMode="EditForms"            AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="false" runat="server">
                <ClientSettings>
                    <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true" />
                    <ClientEvents OnCommand="onCommand" />
                </ClientSettings>
                <MasterTableView ShowFooter="true" ClientDataKeyNames="ItemID" TableLayout="Auto" EditMode="InPlace">
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ItemCode" HeaderText="Item" UniqueName="Item"
                            HeaderStyle-Width="400px" ItemStyle-Width="400px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                            ReadOnly="true">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Test" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                            UniqueName="Test" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" ItemStyle-Width="120px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" ID="Qty" Width="40px"/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="Unit Price" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                            UniqueName="UnitPrice" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                            DataFormatString="{0:N}" ReadOnly="true">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LineTotalExVat" HeaderText="Total (Excl VAT)"
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" UniqueName="LineTotalExVat" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                            ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataFormatString="{0:N}"
                            ReadOnly="true">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="VAT" HeaderText="VAT" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                            DataFormatString="{0:N}" ReadOnly="true">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LineTotal" HeaderText="Line Total" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                            DataFormatString="{0:N}" ReadOnly="true">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridButtonColumn HeaderText="Delete" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
                            ItemStyle-Width="50px" HeaderStyle-Width="50px">
                        </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The problem is when I launch the website I get the following: see below image:

[image]

The custom column doesn't appear on all the rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I managed to sort this out by changing the `PageSize="1"` to read `PageSize="1000"` so the first 1000 records on my RadGrid will display my custom ColumnTemplate.